# Python: should I use eval, exec or ..?

Tags: python, exec, eval

I am trying to make the following statement more flexible:

```
for posting in page.findAll(attrs = {"id": re.compile(r'''post\d+''')}):
```

The following part is retrieved dynamically from a CSV file and stored in a string (for example the string called test). The CSV is stored in a secure location, accessible for admins only.

```
attrs = {"id": re.compile(r'''post\d+''')}
```

Can I integrate the variable as following by using an eval(test) or exec(test) in stead of just test?

```
for posting in page.findAll(test)):
```

Comment: @user620007: First.  You can omit "Dear," and "Thanks".  They don't help.  Really.  It's not rude to omit this.  Second.  Please look at your question.  the "bold" thing didn't work, did it?  Please **update** your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Third, welcome to SO. Fresh blood is good for the community, even if you don't know all of our quirks yet.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run code from user input (file contents are input), you'll need `eval` or `exec`, by these names or some other (specifically, you need `exec` for statements - assignment is a statement).

But you don't want to (and shouldn't) do that, because that's evil, insecure, totally unnecessary, etc. Drop the assignment (just store the dict) and the `re.compile` call, then you can use `ast.literal_eval` on it and you're quite safe (you should still catch syntax errors and everything else that may go wrong to display a sensible error message, but malicious code should be close to impossible and it's not nearly as dirty). You can apply the `re.compile` after loading if you thing it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have absolutely no control over the CSV source, avoid, at all cost these kinds of loading.

- save the regex as seriliazed data using the `pickle` module (or better, just save the string)
- Save your data as JSON using the `json` module
- write it to a file using the `csv` module

Then do the opposite to get the data from the file.

If you can't control the CSV generation, try extracting the data manually using `split` or the `re` module.

`eval` and `exec` are 'last chance solution'. Avoid using them unless you have no other ways.

Comment: The CSV is stored in a secure location, accessible for admins only.

Comment: @user620007: Are you an admin building the system, or just trying to interface with someone else's system?

Answer (score 1):

The most secure is [ast.literal_eval()](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> args = ast.literal_eval('{"a":1}')
>>> args
{'a': 1}
```

You can use it as:

```
some_function_or_method(**args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither - this is Python - you can write a eries of named parameters and the desired values to call a function as  dictionary. In this case, a dictionary which value fot the key "attrs" is also a dictionary. Just prepend to "**" to the dictionary name when calling the function:

```
test= {"attrs": {\"id\": re.compile(r'''post\d+''')} }

for posting in page.findAll(**test}):
   (...)
```

Comment: The question is about loading the `attrs` dynamically from a file, not about unpacking a dictionary.

Comment: And so, what is the problem with populating your data as strings in the dictionary from the data on your file?